# JSONPath returns JProperty instead of JObject

Tags: json, json.net, jsonpath

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "signed": {
    "delegations": {
      "keys": {
        "blubb": {
          "keytype": "rsa-x509",
          "keyval": {
            "private": null,
            "public": "SomeOtherValue"
          }
        },
        "d8674eb06f5aac8d003b2f309e302fd0a82414074acc9a626e0b447704f2a2b8": {
          "keytype": "rsa-x509",
          "keyval": {
            "private": null,
            "public": "SomeValue"
          }
        }
      },
      "roles": [{
          "keyids": ["d8674eb06f5aac8d003b2f309e302fd0a82414074acc9a626e0b447704f2a2b8"],
          "name": "targets/abc",
          "paths": [""],
          "threshold": 1
        }, {
          "keyids": ["blubb"],
          "name": "targets/def",
          "paths": [""],
          "threshold": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to get the "SomeValue" for the key with the same name as the roles.keyids[0] where the corresponding name is "targets/abc".

I tried the following:

```
$.signed.delegations.keys[?($.signed.delegations.roles[?(@name == 'targets/abc')])].keyval.public
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you expect your `SelectTokens()` query to return.  The first query returns nothing; the second query returns 2 values: `SomeOtherValue` and `SomeValue`.  Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5nGqcP.  Is that what you want?

Comment: No, I actually want it to return "SomeValue" only. The "working" query didn't work, I removed it from the question. I was mistaken.

Comment: I'll be happy to be proven wrong, but this calls for nested filters, but AFAIK, these aren't supported by jsonpath.

Comment: I see, hmm. I will use two queries then instead as a workaround.